# correctly align html divs with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This may be a simple question, but I am stumped at how I can solve the issue that I have.

I have a series of div's that display the users contact details.

When **all** the users contact details are supplied, the display of the contact details is aligned correctly, like this:

[image]

However, when only some of the contact details are supplied, the contact details are not correctly aligned. Here is a preview, where the user has not supplied their email address:

[image]

**How do I align the details when only some of the users details are supplied using CSS?** I am using twitter bootstrap 2.3 for the responsive design, so I assumed that the span4 (permitting 3 contact details per line) would align correctly, but it does not.

I have searched SO for a solution, but came up blank. I have tried a few fixes but nothing I can think of works.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="resumeStyleStandardNacContactContainer25" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
    {{ #if contact_details_phone }}
        <span class="span4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
            <i class="icon-phone icon_size20"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ contact_details_phone }}
        </span>
    {{ /if }}
    {{ #if contact_details_mobile_phone }}
        <span class="span4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
            <i class="icon-phone icon_size20"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ contact_details_mobile_phone }}
        </span>
    {{ /if }}
    {{ #if contact_details_email_address }}
        <span class="span4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
            <i class="icon-email icon_size20"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ contact_details_email_address }}
        </span>
    {{ /if }}
    {{ #if contact_details_linkedin_address }}
        <span class="span4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
            <i class="icon-linkedin icon_size20"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="btu-link">{{ contact_details_linkedin_address }}</span>
        </span>
    {{ /if }}
    {{ #if contact_details_facebook_address }}
        <span class="span4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
            <i class="icon-facebook icon_size20"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="btu-link">{{ contact_details_facebook_address }}</span>
        </span>
    {{ /if }}
    {{ #if contact_details_twitter_address }}
        <span class="span4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
            <i class="icon-twitter icon_size20"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="btu-link">{{ contact_details_twitter_address }}</span>
        </span>
    {{ /if }}
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.resumeStyleStandardNacContactContainer25 {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a JS fiddle or some such? You might need to at a set width to each container otherwise it will try to push everything together. It's kinda hard to picture without a working example. Sorry.

Comment: Step one: don't use `&nbsp;&nbsp;` for spacing, use `margin` or `padding` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `if` statement inside the block that you see disappearing. 
But then you need to calculate the amount of Bootstrap columns needed instead of `span4`.

This looks like this would work, but it will leave holes and without a JSFiddle we cannot be completely sure.

For example;

```
<span class="span4 ellipsis" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">
    {{ #if contact_details_phone }}
    <i class="icon-phone icon_size20"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {{ contact_details_phone }}
    {{ /if }}
</span>
```

An other way to do it, is to `foreach` loop every possible contact detail possibility (and options like icon and url), check if the value exists, but again you may need to calculate what `span4` should be.